# How to export current year posts from Wordpress?

Tags: query

I have very big Wordpress database, in which I am storing the records from year(2013) and now I want to export only current year(2018) posts from the database and also want to import it into staging server Wordpress's website.

I am looking for a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at WPs default export tool (Tools > Export). You can set a date range when exporting posts, doesn't this suffice?

Answer (score 1):

The core version of WordPress (i.e. with no plugins installed) has export functionality built-in. You will find the export feature in the main WordPress admin menu in the **Tools** section.

There are three options available. The first option backs up all content including posts, pages, comments, custom fields, categories and tags.

Alternatively, you can choose to only export posts or pages. You can filter what is exported and only export content from particular categories, authors, **date range** and publication status.

Comment: date range? where?